# Axis2 sending multipart response when content-type is "text/xml"

Tags: soap, response, apache-axis

Axis2 by default is send a multipart response even when there are no attachments

Why is axis2 sending a multipart response & how to ask it to send a "application/xml" or "application/soap+xml"  how to get rid of multipart?
In the axis2.xml I have

In the response I see
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 17 Feb 2017 01:07:08 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="MIMEBoundary_87162747c87b279f7caa4e1ab573d5d864a878de7fae1a0b"; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<0.97162747c87b279f7caa4e1ab573d5d864a878de7fae1a0b@apache.org>"; start-info="text/xml"

--MIMEBoundary_87162747c87b279f7caa4e1ab573d5d864a878de7fae1a0b
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.97162747c87b279f7caa4e1ab573d5d864a878de7fae1a0b@apache.org>

200<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<List_Wrapper>
<_bp>

<_comments><_comment><content>Again a new comment this is a text type bp comment need to see this in the text json 1</content><published_date>2017-01-18T21:07:15</published_date><published_by>cyril furtado</published_by><company>Chevron Inc.</company></_comment></_comments></_bp>
</List_Wrapper>

--MIMEBoundary_87162747c87b279f7caa4e1ab573d5d864a878de7fae1a0b-

Answer (score 1):

I too faced similar issue for AXIS 2 quite recently , so thought to answer this.

AXIS 2 by default support attachment processing globally, which might not be needed for all types of services. To resolve this issue I disabled MTOM processing globally by modifying axis2.xml file -

```
<parameter name="enableMTOM">false</parameter>
```

This capability can now be enabled on need basis per service basis by enabling this property via respective services.xml file